# How to parse time field into hours, minutes and seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I parse my `start_at` column to be three different fields for hours, minutes and seconds instead of just one?

**Note**: I want to keep it as one column and not make three different ones.

Here is my code:

Table:

```
class CreateTimers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :timers do |t|
      t.time :start_at

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@timer) do |f| %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.text_field :start_at %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Start', :class => 'btn-primary span3' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have some samples of the values you are working on? Are they always HH:MM:SS format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to split time to three separate inputs you can use the [`time_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_select) helper.

Otherwise use the `strftime` method; Check http://strfti.me for more help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what format your time values are in. Because users love to be different, if you give them a free-form text field, odds are really good you'll get data in varying formats, so you'll have to be flexible.

You can try using DateTime's [`parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-parse) method, which provides some flexibility for the formats.

```
DateTime.parse('2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00')
#=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00 ...>

DateTime.parse('20010203T040506+0700')
#=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T04:05:06+07:00 ...>

DateTime.parse('3rd Feb 2001 04:05:06 PM')
#=> #<DateTime: 2001-02-03T16:05:06+00:00 ...>
```

There's also the [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) gem, which allows even more flexibility in how the values can be entered.

Once you have a DateTime or Time value, you can use that object's methods to get at the hour, minute and second fields:

```
now = Time.now # => 2012-10-03 07:50:26 -0700
now.hour       # => 7
now.min        # => 50
now.sec        # => 26
```

or:

```
require 'date'
now = DateTime.now # => #<DateTime: 2012-10-03T07:52:53-07:00 ((2456204j,53573s,622304000n),-25200s,2299161j)>
now.hour # => 7
now.min  # => 52
now.sec  # => 53
```

Answer (score 1):

For e.g.

```
start_at - 2011-04-26 04:14:56 UTC
```

For hours:

```
start_at.strftime("%H") = "04"
```

For minutes:

```
start_at.strftime("%M") = "14"
```

For seconds:

```
start_at.strftime("%S") = "26"
```

Comment: detailed description of strftime you can find on the link provided by @surase.prasad

Comment: `%Y` is years, `%y` is a two-digit year, `%m` is months and `%d` is days. How do those relate to hours, minutes and seconds that the OP asked for?

Comment: ohh shit sorry I am just editing the answer don't know why I wrote that answer...

Comment: Now show an example parsing all three values from one string and we'll call it good. :-)

Comment: I have given that too :P ...now happy @theTinMan :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check out `strftime` at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html

Answer (score 1):

```
start_at.strftime("%H %M %S")
```

More detailed documentation is at: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html

Comment: The OP wants hours, minutes, seconds, not years, months and days.

Comment: @theTinMan: sorry, overlooked the question, updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.